# Как изменить иконку в MainActivity?

Tags: android

Видимо это баг

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Слева сверху это моя программа. Иконка установилась drawer, хотя у меня стоит обычная стандартная зеленая иконка андроида
[image: Drawer Icon]

Если установить в `<activity icon`, какую нибудь иконку, то почему то измениться иконка как в самом приложении так же и в Laucnhere, и в меню выбора установленных приложений.

Как изменить иконку в `MainActivity`?

P.S. предложения типо из кода вставлять иконку не вариант. Так как при запуске я увижу вначале `ic_launcher` а спустя 3 сек. только установиться та иконка которая была прописана в коде `MainACtivity` через `getActionBar()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

activity icon не должен влиять на иконку в лаунчере. Попробуйте полностью удалить приложение с девайса, и установить заново.

Comment: Обновил вопрос глянеьт

Comment: Кстати заметье на Текст.

Текст ТОЖЕ ПРОПАЛ))